# SVG vs Canvas, to use graphic based application

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, canvas, svg

Hi I am trying develop a graphic based application with drag and drop.

I have attached images of my application.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4i7m97t_5pNFRTaTQ4YmE2YlU/view?usp=sharing

These are the actions I wanted to use in my application
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4i7m97t_5pX1RGUUFWMk9rNEU/view?usp=sharing

Each and every actions(like drag and drop), I needed a service call and redraw the layout based on the response.

Currently I have used html elements like div and span. But it is very heavy weighted, and feeling lagging while using drag and drop or some other action. I am thinking to convert to svg or Canvas.

Which is better to use this scenario. I should very flexible to use(without lagging). It should be light weight.

also I needed to use angular for services.

Comment: http://angular-js.in/angular-gridster/ you can try this one.

Answer (score 2):

Although this has been asked a lot of times before,

For interactive drawing apps (where you can pick-up the shapes etc) *it's best to use SVG.*

- *They are manipulatable, by nature of their design* - SVG elements are regular DOM
  elements thus you can easily attach click handlers on them, transform their positions etc.
- *Redraw operations are efficiently handled by the browser* so they are faster when many items are involved

Canvas on the other hand uses a fire-and-forget type of drawing mode - You are simply drawing *pixels, not objects* on a canvas and there is no memory of the objects/elements you've drawn unless you built this functionality/structure yourself in your app (which would be a huge overkill) - It knows that pixel has been drawn at a position but it does not hold any representation of the object itself (e.g a square/line etc)

You can use any of the Canvas libraries ([Paper.js](http://paperjs.org), [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) etc) which emulate an SVG-like retained-drawing mode on a [Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) as well, but from my experience they tend to be slow in the long-run since they naively redraw the *whole* scene when something has changed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks alot Nicholas. How about "Raphael js" to use for draw svg.

Comment: @user2463011 Highly recommended